# iOS - How to reference views in view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

From an android background, each UI Element (i.e., "widget") has an id. For example, `userNameInputText` could be an id that maps to a specific text field. What is the analog for iOS?

In Xcode, I define views in my storyboard, then `ctrl`+drag them to my ViewController class. This allows me to set up listeners, etc. However, it seems that something is being obscured. How does the listener reference back to the specific view? In android this would be obvious because you must explicitly provide the element's id.

Comment: You can assign a `tag` number and locate the required view by tag but is is far simpler and more efficient to create an `@IBOutlet` property and link this to the appropriate UI element.

Comment: The reference is purely based upon the variable name? In the case of `@IBOutlet weak var userNameInputText: UITextField!`, the only way the ViewController knows which view it references is to use the name `userNameInputText`? If so, how does the ViewController connect this name to the view?

Comment: Well yeah.  When you write code you know which UI element you need to access and just access it.  As I said you can assign an id in the `tag` property, but generally don't need to

Comment: Does this name, `userNameInputText`, also appear in the storyboard file? I cannot find it. If not, how does the ViewController know which view it's really controlling?

Comment: It's magic that you try not to worry about. Coming from C#, many aspects of XCode look clunky - particularly hooking up views and event handlers. Still, there are plenty of upsides.

Comment: How then do I, as a programmer, know which view `userNameInputText` is referencing? Say, if I am working with a new code base.

Comment: You create the link in InterfaceBuilder to the IBOutlet in your view controller.  The link is recorded in the XML file somewhere but you don't need to worry about it.  When you scene is instantiated from the storyboard the items are connected to the properties into the view controller instance.  If you click on the item in storyboard you can see the outlet that it is connected to in the connections inspector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I define views in my storyboard, then ctrl+drag them to my ViewController class. This allows me to set up listeners, etc

Control-drag not only allows you to add listeners. It also allows you to add *outlet* connections. An outlet connection looks like this in code:

```
@IBOutlet var myUIElement: UIXXXX!
```

You can use the identifier `myUIElement` to reference the view. Here's an example of how to add an outlet connection:

- Control-drag a view, say `UIImageView` to the View Controller class and this appears:

[image]

See the word "Outlet" there? That means you are adding an outlet connection. And let's call the outlet `myImage`. So in code, this will look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
```

And now you have a reference to the image view in your storyboard! Just like in Java, but shorter.  Let me write this in Java so you get a clearer picture:

```
private ImageView myImage;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setLayout(R.layout.someLayout);
    myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.someId);
}
```

If you want to get back a prototype table view cell, there's another method:

- In the storyboard, select the cell, and add a reuse identifier to the cell, say `my cell`.
- In the table view controller, call this method:

  ```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("my cell")
  ```

And now you can get the cell!

Comment: Is the latter code still correct? XCode seems to require `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my cell ")` nowadays

Comment: @phihag that’s right. This answer is in Swift 2 IIRC.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm new to iOS (more used to Android) and am having the hardest time wrapping my head around this. Does this work without the drag/drop mechanism ? If not, I imagine Xcode is generating some other code somewhere that links the outlet to the specific view. If it does, then how is the linking done? If I create a second view with exactly the same attributes in my storyboard, which one is linked by the outlet?

Comment: @ChrisNeve This is Xcode magic. During compilation, the storyboard is compiled into a nib file. Then at runtime, when the View Controller is being initialised, it reads the nib file, and initialises all the `IBOutlet` properties according to the file contents.

Comment: @Sweeper OK, so this won't work without the drag and drop mechanism, right?

Comment: @ChrisNeve Well, the storyboard file is just an XML file. Drag-dropping simply adds a new `<outlet>` tag under the `<connections>` tag in that view controller. So technically you can just edit the storyboard file directly, but I'm sure everyone just drags and drops.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the content of a xib file, you will find something like
`<view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">`

So I think xCode uses generated identifiers to connect these views to your IBOutlets.